# Filter records by interval date in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

I'm creating a filter to get expenses on a Credit Card, to generate a invoice.

But I only made it work filtering by month and year. I need get the records on days interval, and than, month and year.

For example:

- **Table**: credit_cards
- **Column**: close_invoice *(day 25)*

How do I get all expenses between day 25 of previous month and the next day 25?

This is my query filtering by month:

```
    $thisMonth = $now->format('m');
    $thisYear = $now->format('Y');

    $cc_expenses = Expense::where([
        ['bank_id', $bank->id],
        ['payment_method', 1],
        ['parcels', NULL]
    ])
        ->whereYear('date', $thisYear)
        ->whereMonth('date', $thisMonth)
        ->get();
```

But this way I don't get the records between day 25 and the last day of the previous month.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$previousMonthLastDay = now()->subMonth()->setDay(25)->setHour(0)->setMinute(0)->setSecond(0);

 ->whereBetween('date', [$previousMonthLastDay, now()])
```

I think nobody need to set future time from now, but if you need, you can do like `$previousMonthLastDay without subMonth()`

if your now date is `2022-04-13 12:22:10` , $previousMonthLastDay will be like `2022-04-25 00:00:00`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how I make ->whereBetween('date' , [2022-03-25, 2022-04-25]); and today is 2022-04-13

Comment: okay, let me update. i think you have this two times.